# 0.1μs delay for AT89C51

Tags: led, atmel, 8051, ws2812b

I need to follow WS2812B protocol, which requires communication with very high speed, like 0.4μs, 0.45μs, etc. Can I achieve it with AT89C51?

Comment: Why are you considering a "C" part? And why oh why and 8051 core device? I have used hundreds old the Intel versions, still have boxes of them, and have used the atmel at89C51 too. A lot. What's driving your choice here? I'm flummoxed.

Comment: @periblepsis It's the only device i have right now, so i was wondering if it's possible. So is it possible or i should wait and get other MCU? What MCU would you suggest for ws2812b protocol?

Comment: I don't know anything about the ws2812b protocol. I'm assuming you do and from what you said if be looking elsewhere. Can you provided a useful link to the protocol?

Comment: @periblepsis this is datasheet: https://voltiq.ru/datasheets/WS2812B_datasheet_EN.pdf

Comment: @periblepsis protocol uses times like 0.4μs, 0.25μs, etc. That's why im not sure, if AT89C51 can update this fast.

Comment: You did read the data sheet and the user manual of the AT89C51, didn't you? What especially did you not understand? Which different approaches did you investigate? -- At a quick glance, I don't think that you can realize the requirements with the AT89C51.

Comment: @thebusybee Yeah, i've read datasheet and was not sure, if there's any way to do it. Actually the xtal in Atmel AT89C51 has maximum oscilator clock speed of 24MHZ which is approximately 0.5μs for 1 instruction. I heared, that actual protocol threshold is way bigger(like 2-3 times bigger), than stated in datasheet, but i don't have LED strip at me now, so i can't check it by myself.

Comment: @SasisaPlay It appears that the specification is *quite poor*. When I read it, it didn't contain anything like what I'd like to see and some of it seemed ... questionable. So I went looking around. [This page](https://cpldcpu.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/light_ws2812-library-v2-0-part-i-understanding-the-ws2812/) is probably worth reading. It points out, for example, something entirely missing from the spec you provided -- that the whole thing might reset if less than 9 microseconds of inactive time occurs. Yet the spec says 50 us. Already here a serious flaw.

Comment: @SasisaPlay So I think there's a need to first get the specifications locked down into a well-understood set. One cannot even begin to ask if an MCU can handle it, if one has no idea what exactly it is that must be handled. Learning that a reset might happen in less than 9 us tells us something very important about requiring timing. And there are so many other questions, now. Too early to be deciding on an MCU, for those of us ignorant of fuller spec, anyway.

Comment: @periblepsis your excellent link continues with [this page](https://cpldcpu.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/light_ws2812-library-v2-0/) which shows how to bitbang this protocol on ATTiny85, with links to a github repository, so it does seem possible.

Comment: **After** fixing the requirement side of the task, you can check whether bit banging in code is possible. An alternative is the shift-register mode (mode 0) of the serial module, if you prepare the bytes to send beforehand. It sends at Fosc./12...